# How to properly center rotated(90) text in a bootstrap col-md-1

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am playing with a layout I wanted to make it look like a dossier with sidetabs.  Am organizing it with bootstrap elements--> a container with `col-10 col-offset-1`, and a sidetab container of `col-1` which contains the side tab elements.

I have found some CSS solutions using `margin-top`, `padding-top` and `translateY()` of the `.vertical-text` (a paragraph element inside the sideTab).  However, my problem is that I want the word to be properly centered in the tab regardless of the length of it -- I have tried text-align, and will continue along that route but have yet to find a satisfactory solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/nacmonad/2dutL3v2/11/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.sideTab').click(function() {

    var tab_id = $('p', this).attr('id');
    console.log(tab_id);
    $('.sideTab').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

})
```

```css
  #content {
    background-color: #669966;
    height: auto;
    /*font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; */
    color: #efefef;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 320px;
  }
  .tabHolder {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 35px;
  }
  .sideTab {
    background-color: #666666;
    width: 35px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
    color: #efefef;
  }
  .sideTab.hover {
    background-color: #669966;
    color: #efefef;
  }
  .sideTab.current {
    background-color: #669966;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  /*help here prrrz*/
  .vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 50%);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .vertical-text:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 10 0 0 0 !important;
  }
  .tab-content {
    display: none;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .tab-content.current {
    display: inherit;
  }
  .current {
    background-color: #669966;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Foldertabs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="content" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
      <p id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">Vocent meliore ea qui, ne solum accommodare vim, eam id elit eirmod invenire. Ius integre singulis nominati eu, habeo consequat argumentum eos ea. Has tempor populo denique cu, ex pro sanctus maiestatis argumentum. Mea tation prompta assentior an,
        nam soluta copiosae legendos et, propriae adolescens dissentiunt et vim. Has ad timeam euismod definitiones, doctus invidunt ex usu, et gloriatur adversarium qui. No libris docendi sensibus pro.</p>
      <p id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Vix exerci mediocritatem in, debet voluptaria interesset mei cu. His quot tation ea, eu discere insolens incorrupte vis. Quot prodesset consequuntur nec ex, quo in tantas voluptua appellantur. Postulant appellantur an vix, te qui graeco option consequuntur.
        Malorum ocurreret contentiones et sed, pro id dolorem percipitur cotidieque.</p>
      <p id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, munere tamquam mediocritatem et has. No vim hinc cetero scaevola, ei est ignota salutandi constituam. Qui in nusquam forensibus, eos dolore splendide democritum et, an ipsum legendos vel. Ut populo utroque pro</p>
      <p id="tab-4" class="tab-content">Vocent meliore ea qui, ne solum accommodare vim, eam id elit eirmod invenire. Ius integre singulis nominati eu, habeo consequat argumentum eos ea. Has tempor populo denique cu, ex pro sanctus maiestatis argumentum. Mea tation prompta assentior an,
        nam soluta copiosae legendos et, propriae adolescens dissentiunt et vim. Has ad timeam euismod definitiones, doctus invidunt ex usu, et gloriatur adversarium qui. No libris docendi sensibus pro.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 tabHolder nopadding">
      <div class="sideTab">
        <p id="tab-1" class="vertical-text">home</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sideTab">
        <p id="tab-2" class="vertical-text">bl.ocks</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sideTab">
        <p id="tab-3" class="vertical-text">about</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sideTab">
        <p id="tab-4" class="vertical-text">contact</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.sideTab').click(function() {

        var tab_id = $('p', this).attr('id');
        console.log(tab_id);
        $('.sideTab').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
      })

    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone point out an obvious solution that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

```
.vertical-text {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(90deg);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(90deg);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.sideTab {
    position: relative;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/2dutL3v2/24/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which will avoid many static pixel values  and instead use the powerful flex to align items and to assign equal dimensions to elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.sideTab').click(function() {

    var tab_id = $('p', this).attr('id');
    console.log(tab_id);
    $('.sideTab').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

})
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: #669966;
  height: auto;
  /*font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; */
  color: #efefef;
  height: 320px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.tabHolder {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
.tabHolder.current {} .sideTab {
  background-color: #666666;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  color: #efefef;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.sideTab:hover {
  background-color: #669966;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}
.vertical-text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
.current {
  background-color: #669966;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.margin-0 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container flex">
  <div id="content" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 flex">
    <p id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">Vocent meliore ea qui, ne solum accommodare vim, eam id elit eirmod invenire. Ius integre singulis nominati eu, habeo consequat argumentum eos ea. Has tempor populo denique cu, ex pro sanctus maiestatis argumentum. Mea tation prompta assentior an,
      nam soluta copiosae legendos et, propriae adolescens dissentiunt et vim. Has ad timeam euismod definitiones, doctus invidunt ex usu, et gloriatur adversarium qui. No libris docendi sensibus pro.</p>
    <p id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Vix exerci mediocritatem in, debet voluptaria interesset mei cu. His quot tation ea, eu discere insolens incorrupte vis. Quot prodesset consequuntur nec ex, quo in tantas voluptua appellantur. Postulant appellantur an vix, te qui graeco option consequuntur.
      Malorum ocurreret contentiones et sed, pro id dolorem percipitur cotidieque.</p>
    <p id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, munere tamquam mediocritatem et has. No vim hinc cetero scaevola, ei est ignota salutandi constituam. Qui in nusquam forensibus, eos dolore splendide democritum et, an ipsum legendos vel. Ut populo utroque pro</p>
    <p id="tab-4" class="tab-content">Vocent meliore ea qui, ne solum accommodare vim, eam id elit eirmod invenire. Ius integre singulis nominati eu, habeo consequat argumentum eos ea. Has tempor populo denique cu, ex pro sanctus maiestatis argumentum. Mea tation prompta assentior an,
      nam soluta copiosae legendos et, propriae adolescens dissentiunt et vim. Has ad timeam euismod definitiones, doctus invidunt ex usu, et gloriatur adversarium qui. No libris docendi sensibus pro.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 tabHolder nopadding">
    <div class="sideTab current flex">
      <p id="tab-1" style="width:47px;" class="vertical-text margin-0">home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideTab flex">
      <p id="tab-2" style="width:47px;" class="vertical-text margin-0">bl.ocks</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideTab flex">
      <p id="tab-3" style="width:47px;" class="vertical-text margin-0">about</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideTab flex">
      <p id="tab-4" style="width:47px;" class="vertical-text margin-0">contact</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I have removed many pixel values which you used to give height and width. Much cleaner solution !.
Surprisingly the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for this awesome property is good.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, try to avoid associating flexbox with Bootstrap 3. There can be small rendering bugs due to commonly used pseudo hacks (such as clearing using pseudo-elements with `display:table`). I love flexbox and I really look forward to Twitter Bootstrap 4 but, after having to fix some mind-boggling bugs in different browsers I came to the conclusion I should try to avoid mixing flexbox with TB3. This is not a critique, it's just sharing knowledge :). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I haven't  used bootstrap much. But yes I agree to the fact that one should play with rows and columns and let the framework do the magic. Good to know that you are a fan of flexbox too. Waiting for a css framework to embrace the power of this gemstone .